# odoo 8 upgrade module from command line

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to upgrade my module from command line so I dont have to upgarde it from odoo dashboard. I have tried command like this but failed.

```
cd odoo-server
./odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf -d ddf_production -u mi_report_activity_sales
```

The error that I get is

```
No such file or directory
```

I'm using odoo 8. What command should I use to make it run without error?

Comment: Check if you actually have the file `./odoo-bin` and `/etc/odoo-server.conf` in place.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a similar error message in the [convert](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/tools/convert.py#L187) file

You can get the same error message using the field tag and setting the `type` attribute to `file` with some text in the field body

***Example:***

```
<field name="image" type="file">text</field>
```

The correct way to use it is as follows:

```
<field name="image" type="base64" file="base/static/img/public_user-image.png"/>
```